# Discord.js Issue with ".addRole"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, roblox

So, I have been having issues setting up a bot that roles a user to a role that includes emoticons. Example:

```
    const guildMember = message.member;
    guildMember.addRole('<@&439191493169643521>');
```

I've also tried:

```
    // content.js
    const guildMember = message.member;
    guildMember.addRole(config.n);

    // config.json
    {
        "n": "Fox"
    }
```

and also I've tried it without config.json, and just put the raw rank name, but it always doesn't work.

This is the Console:

```
      (node:15600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
      (node:15600) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Forgot to add: 
the reason I added "roblox" as a tag is because I am using `npm roblox-js` too for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.`

Well, `Fox`is not a Role Object and is also not a Snowflake (ID).
To add a role you need or a Object or a ID.

If you want to use the ID, you will need to make the role mentionable and then escape the mention `\@MyRole`, then just copy the ID (it's only the numbers) and use it:

```
guildMember.addRole('439191493169643521');
```

If you want to still go use the name of the role, you can do something like this:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'MyRole');
guildMember.addRole(role);
```